# How do I split/splice and realign parts of tracks in Garage Band?

Tags: editing, garageband

I used Garage Band 6.0.5 in conjunction with a Shure Beta87 microphone and AudioBox USB to record my son and friends singing made up lyrics to a song for a school project. I recorded 6 'takes' of them singing and would like to splice together the best portions of each take and layer that on top of an instrumental version of the song. In some cases, the timing is off.

1. How to split/splice tracks?
2. Is there a way to 'realign' a portion of a track to get it back in time?

Comment: You don't need AVP for this, this can be found in garage band help or simply be searching it but I will help anyway. Both are possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this situation I would recommend Audacity. This is how you can do it in Garage Band. To splice, simply double click on the track you want to splice, go to the slider that popped up and go to the bottom section of the track. Here you can select, select what you want to delete and ether 1, double click to make it into a separate clip or 2, press delete. To quantize it, go under Audio Region, click on the drop down under "Quantize Note Timing" and select the timing, this will quantize the whole track. If you click in the top section of a track, you can drag waveforms to the correct position. I will put pictures if you are still confused.

Comment: This helped me visualize the split/splice. http://www.ehow.com/video_2372696_split-join-tracks-garageband.html. Still working on the Quantization.

Comment: So do you still need help on quantization?